# Problem with inserting a picture into Excel sheet in NETLink way

Tags: .netlink, excellink

I'm using the `NETLink` to work with `Excel` object, there be differences to write code according to the `NETLink` user manual in `Mathematica` from `C#`, but it's hard to do more in fact.

I wanted to put a picture in `Excel` `ActiveSheet`, the `MSDN` gvies notation [like this](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.office.interop.excel.pictures.insert?view=excel-pia) in C#:

```
public Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Picture Insert (string Filename, object Converter);
```

first time I trans it as

```
activesheet@Cells[20, 1]@Select[]
activesheet@Pictures@Insert["E:\\birds.png"]
```

error ocurred. ... at last, the code was changed to

```
activesheet@Cells[20, 1]@Select[]    
activesheet@Pictures[]@Insert["E:\\birds.png"]
```

and it worked. I donot know why paired brackets is necessary for the `Pictures`?
so I hope there be particular Classes browser for `NETLink` more than the `NETTypeInfo` function to help understand these objects exactly. If there be Classes browser designed for Assembly when using NETLink would be better?

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The crux of the issue is that the symbol `WorksheetClass.Pictures` is a method, not a property.  When using NETLink, methods must always be followed by an argument list, even when no arguments are being specified.

We can distinguish between methods and properties by inspecting the `NETTypeInfo`:

```
NETTypeInfo["Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.WorksheetClass"]
```

[image: NETTypeInfo screenshot]

Here we see that `Pictures` is a method that takes a single optional index argument.

Comment: Yes, thanks! I hope there be  `GUI` tool  in NETLink package to help looking up like object browser in VisualStudio IDE